# Creating a .NET List<List<double>> to call a .NET DLL from MATLAB?

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, generics

I have a .NET DLL I'm loading into MATLAB R2016B through the `asm = NET.addAssembly('C:\My.dll')`  It is fairly easy to create a  .NET list of doubles using `netDouble = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{'System.Double'},1)` which MATLAB shows as `1x1 List<System*Double>`, but there is no tutorial out there that shows how to create a .NET `List<List<double>>` structure.  MATLAB can't access the code I need to run as a result - it shows the error as: `Value must be
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System*Collections*Generic*List<System*Double>>'.`

Anyone out there know how to create the above structure?  Much appreciated.

Comment: My trial of MATLAB has expired, so I can't test this, but have you tried `NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>'},1)`?

Comment: Unfortunately MATLAB doesn't seem to like that embedded Generic inside the second field: Message: Could not load the type
'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Double>'.
Source: dotnetcli

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually MATHWORKS tech support got back to me with a solution that works.  Since I don't see it documented anywhere, I'm posting this example in case someone else runs into this issue:

```
genCls = NET.GenericClass('System.Collections.Generic.List','System.Double');
obj = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{genCls},5);
```

And how they explained it: In this method, we first create a generic class as List and this class is provided as an argument to the 'NET.createGeneric' method hence the created list is of type `List<List<double>>`

Then to populate it... here's a function I wrote to take the Matlab array and convert to the proper type all rolled into 1:

```
function [NETobj] = ML_NET_ListListDouble(MLarray)  
genCls = NET.GenericClass('System.Collections.Generic.List','System.Double');
NETobj = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{genCls},size(MLarray,1));    
for i=1:size(MLarray,1) 
        obj1 = NET.createGeneric('System.Collections.Generic.List',{'System.Double'},size(MLarray,2));
        AddRange(obj1, NET.convertArray(MLarray(i,:))) %insert the current MATLAB row into the NET structure
    Add(NETobj, obj1)
end
end
```

That function hopefully comes in useful for someone else - a brainless conversion from a MATLAB array to a .NET `<List<List<double>>`